# file is not uploading even after using move_upload_file()?

Tags: php

Actually, I am trying to send an image file to db. Instead of picture i m trying to send to picture link ...the values in db are going perfectly fine but there is a problem ...file is not uploading in designated folder..

```
$file_name=$_FILES['images']['name'];    
 $file_tmp =$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];

        $heading=$_POST['heading']['name'];

        $headline=$_POST['headlines']['name'];
        $story=$_POST['story']['name'];
        $date=date("m/d/Y");
    $random = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 13);
 $moved= move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".md5(date('dYm')).$file_name); 


          $url="images/".md5(date('dYm')).$file_name;


          $query="INSERT INTO news(news_id,pic,heading,headline,story,date)
          VALUES('$random','$url','$heading','$headline','$story','$date')";
          $data=mysqli_query($conn,$query); 


if( $moved ) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded";         
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["images"]["error"];
}
```

and this is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(response){
                 alert(response);  
                    if(response.error){
                        alert(response.error);
                    }
                }

           });
```

i m saying again that data is inserting in db absolutely fine..problem is in image uploading

Comment: Try: `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, getcwd() . "/images/"...`

Comment: You are open to sql-injection. Please, yous prepared statements.

Comment: no it doesn't help

Comment: @freeek how can u guide me a little bit?

Comment: @UMARSTACK not me, but [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) can.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging techniques, and if so what errors does it throw?

Comment: using `datatype:'json'` whilst using `FormData` as the payload seems inappropriate. You might also find that you cannot access the uploaded file using `$_FILES` when performing ajax upload like this - though you might find it with `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: @RamRaider can u change the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        ob_clean();

        # A directory, somewhere, to save files to...
        $dir='c:/temp/fileuploads/1/';

        /* The file field name simply for convenience */
        $fieldname='images';

        /* default value for uploaded file if there is a problem */
        $obj=false;




        if( !empty( $_FILES[ $fieldname] ) ){
            /* standard file upload */
            $obj=(object)$_FILES[ $fieldname ];
            $obj->method='FILES';   #   For illustrative porpoises only

        } elseif( !empty( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) ) ){
            /* file upload via other means */
            $obj=file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
            $obj->method='PHP://INPUT'; #   For illustrative porpoises only
        }


        if( $obj ){
            /* extract properties of uploaded file into variables */
            $name=$obj->name;
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $error=$obj->error;
            $type=$obj->type;
            $size=$obj->size;
            $method=$obj->method;

            /* If all is OK, do interesting things */
            if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
                /* Move the file to it's final location, run SQL query */
                $targetpath=$dir . $name;
                $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetpath );

                if( $status ){
                    //$sql='insert into `news` (f1,f2,f3,f4) values (?,?,?,?)'; # etc
                    //$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );                                   # etc
                    //$stmt->bind_param('ssss',$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4);                    # etc
                    //$stmt->execute();                                             # etc
                }
            }
        }

        $json=json_encode( $obj );  // here only to illustrate workings
        exit( $json );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>File upload</title>
        <script>
            let d=document;
                d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                    d.querySelector( 'form > input[ type="button" ]' ).addEventListener('click',e=>{
                        const ajax=function(url,params){
                            const success_callback=function(r){
                                if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 ){
                                    console.info( r );// do more interesting things here than this!!!
                                }
                            };
                            const error_callback=function(e){
                                alert( e )
                            };
                            let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.onload=success_callback;
                                xhr.onerror=error_callback;
                                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                                xhr.send( params );
                        };


                        ajax( location.href, new FormData( document.forms.geronimo ) );
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='geronimo' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='images' />
            <input type='button' value='Upload image and do other stuff' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```